# RSS feed on IIS 7.5, 404.3 error?

Tags: xml, iis, rss, iis-7.5

I am very new to webdesign and using IIS and I am trying to put an RSS feed on my page that has 1 item that is an audio file. I created the .rss file and validated it using an online validator and I put it and the .mp3 file in my wwwroot folder. However when I try to access the rss feed by going to localhost/mypodcast.rss, I get an error screen saying:

> HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL)
>   configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web
>   server.

Here is my .rss file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Calorie Counter</title>
        <link>localhost</link>
        <description>Weight loss website</description>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <copyright>2013</copyright>
        <lastBuildDate>Mon, 19 Aug 2013 12:43:59 

GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>tdscripts.com Podcast 

Generator</generator>       

<webMaster>pdficore@oakland.edu</webMaster>
        <ttl>1</ttl>
        <item>
            <title>Instructions Podcast</title>
            <description>our first 

podcast</description>
            <pubDate>Mon, 19 Aug 2013 12:43:59 

GMT</pubDate>
            <enclosure url="localhost/MyPodcast.mp3" 

length="1837924" type="audio/mpeg"/>
            </item>
        </channel>
    </rss>
```

Is there something I need to configure on the IIS to allow .rss files? Or is there a problem with my .rss file?